# Callbacks in c and pointers in c

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a task to make a function that summarize array and list elements(int type) with callbacks using 2 given signatures :

```
typedef void (* callback )( void * ctx , int * value );
void arrayForeach ( void * ctx , callback func , int * arr , int n );
```

I don't know how I can use function pointers here so I have no idea what to do. Can write this simple code for me and explain what is callback, please.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You should know how to call a function (doing that via a function pointer is not really different)

Comment: For each element of the array you're supposed to call the function with the arguments `ctx` and `value`.

Comment: `callback` is a *type* (like `int` or `double`). `callback func` declares the argument variable `func` being of the type`callback`. Since it's a pointer to a function you cal call it like any other function, with suitable arguments: `func(some_ctx, pointer_to_some_value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  caller must check if arr[0] to arr[n-1] is a valid array or part of an array */
void arrayForEach(int ctx, callback func, int * arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        func(ctx, &arr[i]); // missed the pointer form
        /* you could also use (*func)(ctx, &arr[i]); */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). And I doubt a beginner like the OP know what `__STD_NO_VLA__` is, how to search for it, or what `static n` would mean in an array declaration, so it would probably confuse a beginner more than help. Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, cannot really do bound checks from callee without crashing. So put a warning is better.

Comment: Function parameter declared as `int arr[static n]` *is not* VLA.

Comment: Just an opinion, but C23 will try to drop K&R C function definition, so it is better to have bounds on the left.

Comment: I should have used `#if (__STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L)||(__STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L)||(__STDC_VERSION__== 201710L)`.

Comment: @AbrahamLe there are even plans to make VLA mandatory again, only *automatic* VLAs would be optional

Comment: @AbrahamLe How should i call this function from main? And what is func?